How to efficiently find the smallest missing positive integer in a large, partially sorted array in Java?
I have a large array of integers that is partially sorted, meaning that some parts of the array are in order, but others are not. I need to find the smallest missing positive integer (greater than 0) in this array efficiently without fully sorting the entire array.
For example:
Input:
arr = [3, -1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 2]
Expected Output:
6 (as 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 are present, but 6 is the smallest missing positive integer).
I wrote the following Java code using a HashSet to track the presence of numbers and then looped through to find the smallest missing positive integer:
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SmallestMissingPositive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {3, -1, 4, 1, 5, 0, 2};
                System.out.println(findSmallestMissingPositive(arr));
    }
    
    public static int findSmallestMissingPositive(int[] arr) {
        HashSet<Integer> seen = new HashSet<>();
        for (int num : arr) {
            if (num > 0) {
                seen.add(num);
            }
        }
    
        int smallestMissing = 1;
        while (seen.contains(smallestMissing)) {
            smallestMissing++;
        }
    
        return smallestMissing;
    }
}

This code works but isn’t optimal for very large arrays. I want to optimize it further, potentially without using additional space (e.g., by modifying the input array itself).
My Questions:

Is there a way to solve this problem in O(n) time complexity without additional space?

How can I leverage the partially sorted nature of the array to improve performance?



Welcome to Stack Overflow! To better understand how this site is meant to be used, I recommend these resources: The Tour, How to Ask a Good Question, and other pages in the Help Center. Note the How to Ask points out one thing to be done before asking is "searching for existing questions on this site that may provide an answer". You might find this , among others.

Why the title says python?

Sorry I wrote the wrong title .. I wrote the correct title now.

How much "partially sorted" do you expect? Your example just looks random.

If rearranging the input array is allowed, this can solved without extra space in linear time by moving positive elements that might form a consecutive sequence starting from 1 using their value minus one as the index.
public static int findSmallestMissingPositive(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        int cur = arr[i];
        if (cur > 0 && cur <= arr.length && arr[cur - 1] != cur) {
            arr[i] = arr[cur - 1];
            arr[cur - 1] = cur;
        } else ++i;
    }
    int missing = 1;
    while (missing <= arr.length && arr[missing - 1] == missing) ++missing;
    return missing;
}


Does this work with duplicates?

@גלעדברקן Yes, if there is already an element at the correct position, the current element is skipped (via the check arr[cur - 1] != cur).

I am not sure that this solution is better than the proposed one, I am just putting it to the consideration of those who can elucidate it...
int getMinimumMissing( int arr[] ) {
    int max = 0;
    List<Integer> weHave = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> WeAreMissing = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++ ) {
        if( arr[ i ] > max ) {
            for( int j = max + 1; j < arr[ i ]; j ++ ) {
                WeAreMissing.add( j );
            }
            weHave.add( arr[ i ] );
            max = arr[ i ];
        }
        else {
            WeAreMissing.remove( Integer.valueOf( arr[ i ] ) );
        }
    }
    if( WeAreMissing.size() == 0 )
        return weHave.get( weHave.size() - 1 ) + 1;
    return WeAreMissing.get( 0 );
}


(NB: I'm not an algorithm person)
Since this is essentially a sorting problem, I'd be surprised if you could do better than O(n log n) in the average case. However, you say that the array is partially ordered, so maybe the  Timsort sorting algorithm could be suitable.
Of course, there might be a faster solution if the maximum integer value is known and of reasonable low magnitude to just allocate an index array and mark the presence of seen values.

We don't need to know the maximum integer value; it suffices to see that the maximum missing positive integer is always at most one larger than the length of array. Thus, one can, in fact, do better than Ω(n log n) in the worst case if modifying the input array.

@Unmitigated Clever!
